# Are there any simple PhoneGap tutorials?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have found zillions of tutorials that none of them was clarifying all information to get started easily with phonegap.
And phonegap documentation it self is pretty confusing and bulky. 
However, my request is:
A simple tutorial to build jquerymobile web project with phone gap without any extra SDK's
And how to get the debug and release keys for app stores..

Thanks in advance

Comment: The one @Gajotres has looks really good for the latest version (3.2).  The problem is PhoneGap is changing so frequently and the differences between 1.x, 2.x, and 3.x make it hard to keep up for a developer that doesn't use it on a regular basis.

Comment: @L_7337 that's true, the difference between 2.9 tutorials and the phone gap documentation for 3.2 is totally confusing!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a line by line tutorial: http://www.gajotres.net/building-a-native-mobile-app-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile-1-4/

If you need MaxOS version you can find it here: http://www.gajotres.net/creating-phonegap-project-on-macos/

It is my personal blog but there's no point in writing it everything here. Feel free to ask me if you have more questions.

Comment: I'm just having a problem when i try to create a new application following the tutorial
[Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets]

Answer (score 3):

Well it doesn't use jQuery but I have quite a step-by-step PhoneGap tutorial for beginners up at https://github.com/drappenheimer/phonegap-by-dissection

It makes *no* assumptions, and the end result is an actual app! (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drappenheimer.japxlate)

Comment: How is having to use a Linux desktop box make it a beginners tutorial? Isn't that the same as having to use a Linux computer?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start PhoneGap would be this step by step tutorial. [How to install/run PhoneGap on Ubuntu, Step by step guide](http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two another tutorials from the end of 2014.

[Phonegap / Cordova - iOS Tutorial](http://www.cordova-forum.de/index.php/Thread/17-Cordova-Tutorial-iOS-App-Mac-OS-X/)

[Phonegap / Cordova - Android Tutorial](http://www.cordova-forum.de/index.php/Thread/36-Cordova-Tutorial-Android-App-Windows/)

If you need more information about those guides - let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since PhoneGap is evolving every day, I would like to add a few more links to this answer.

Nowadays, you can use Cordova (aka PhoneGap) with any modern web framework such as Angular, React, Vue JS instead of JQuery mobile

Reference Links:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/phonegap/
- [PhoneGap Tutorial](https://codesundar.com/category/phonegap-tutorial/)
- https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6
- http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/12/sample-mobile-application-with-react-and-cordova/